# One single tkinter program wont open on double click. I get no error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

My code for an alarm in tkinter won't open on double click. It runs in idle just fine and all my other tkinter programs open on double click too. What in the code is causing this?

```
from tkinter import * 
import datetime
import time
from time import strftime
import winsound

master = Tk()  
master.geometry('300x300') 
master.title('Alarm Time') 

label = Label(master, text = 'What time would you like to wake up?') 
label.pack() 

EnteredAlarm = Entry(master) 
EnteredAlarm.pack(ipady=8)

def callback():           
    Alarm = EnteredAlarm.get()                
    while True:
        Time = strftime('%H:%M') 


        if str(Time) == str(Alarm): 
            print('Wake up Mister West')
            winsound.PlaySound('Alarm.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            break


        else:
            print('Zzz...')
            time.sleep(5)




b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)   
b.pack()
```

The code doesn't return any errors, all that happens is cmd opens for half a second then closes. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You _call_ `master.mainloop()` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `master.mainloop()` at the end of your program, as the last logical line.

This forces the program to continually update everything.

Comment: I cannot believe that was it, thanks mate. All my other programs work without this which is why I was confused.

Comment: @MaxStrange program can runs without `mainloop()` in IDLE because IDLE is created with `tkinter` and it runs `mainloop()` to work.

Comment: No problem @MaxStrange. If you could mark the answer as correct then that would be great.